# Does Video.io support Xamarin forms

Tags: python, video, xamarin, chat

I want to integrate a video and text chat for web (python) and mobile (xamarin). The requirement is to make customers able to communicate across platforms i.e mobile to web and vice versa.

Mobile application will be developed using Xamarin technology and the website will be in Python.

Is video supported by both platforms?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does, check out the vidyo.io Xamarin sample on github - https://github.com/Vidyo/VidyoConnector-xamarin

Note that vidyo.io SDK runs on the client end. That means it will either run on your mobile device (using native libraries or in your case using Xamarin), or in case of web sites it will use javascript. You do not need to integrate vidyo.io SDK on the server side. 
On your server, what you will need, is to generate "tokens" whenever your client device or website wants to connect to a video conference. 
Since you are using python you can take a look at their sample token generator at https://static.vidyo.io/4.1.16.8/utils/generateToken.py
You can learn more about tokens on their website - 
https://developer.vidyo.io/documentation/4-1-16-8/getting-started#Tokens